# Using const to declare useState function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  function increase() {
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log(count);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={increase}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: useState]

When I console.log the value of count, it increases by 1 even though I have declared it using const. How is it still being updated? I have a feeling it's related to the useState function, but I'm not sure.

Another thing is, if we can update using `count + 1`, why can't we do so using `count++`?

Thanks a lot for the guidance!

Code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/g8dgv0?file=/src/components/App.jsx

Comment: You never actually mutate the `count` variable in your function. When you call `setCount(count + 1)`, your function reexecutes and so a new count variable is created for that invocation with the value you had previously called `setCount()` with. Using `count++` tries to modify the actual `const` variable which isn't allowed.

Answer (score 3):

React is fundamentally a rendering library, and the paradigm it uses is that the info that's rendered on the screen should flow directly from the current state stored in React. So, calling a state setter does *two* things:

- It updates the internal state React has for that state value
- It tells the component to re-render, so as to generate a new view based on the new updated state

Whenever a functional component re-renders, the function runs again - and `useState` can return different values depending on what the current value of the internal state is.

For a similar example in vanilla JS:

```js
let internalValue = false;
const getValue = () => internalValue;
const setValue = (newValue) => {
  internalValue = newValue;
  setTimeout(App);
};

const App = () => {
  const stateValue = getValue();
  if (!stateValue) {
    setValue(true);
  }
  console.log('app rendered with stateValue of', stateValue);
};
App();
```

Above, you can do `const stateValue = getValue();` and get different values for `stateValue` depending on other factors - **because the `App` function ran again**.

> Another thing is, if we can update using count + 1, why can't we do so using count++?

Because, as explained in the beginning of the answer, the view should flow from the state in React, and when updating the state, you need to tell React to re-render; reassigning a variable, by itself, doesn't have side effects. You need to call the state setter to update React's internal state and then re-render with the new state.

So, you need

```
setCount(count + 1);
```

and not

```
count++;
```

because only the former will result in a re-render (even if you had declared `count` with `let`).

Answer (score 1):

The '0' value in your `useState(0)` is the default/initial value that the state will start with. From there you can modify it using `setCount(value)`

For your second question, from [howtojs.io](https://howtojs.io/why-count-do-not-work-with-react-usestate-hook/):

> In React, we should not modify the state variables directly. We need
> to pass the new data to the state variable modifier functions (such as
> setCount), then React will modify the value of the state variable.
>
> One more thing we need to remember is, when we do count++ in
> JavaScript, the variable will be incremented after consuming the
> variable first.
>
> So, when we do setState(count++), first the value of count will be
> passed to the setState function, then the value of count will be
> incremented inside the function component (this is not recommended
> way).

Answer (score 1):

> When I console.log the value of `count`, it increases by 1 even though I
> have declared it using const.

When you are console logging the `count` state you are actually logging the ***unupdated*** current state value. In other words, nothing has changed yet. It's only at the end of the render cycle when enqueued state updates are processed that the component rerenders (*i.e. calls the function body*) with the updated state value.

> How is it still being updated? I have a feeling it's related to the
> `useState` function, but I'm not sure.

Yes, the `useState` hook returns the current state value and a function to call to enqueue an update to state.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

In the `increase` callback handler  the `setCount` function is called with the next value you are *requesting* React to update the state to.

```
function increase() {
  setCount(count + 1);
}
```

As described above, the update is enqueued and at then end of the render cycle is processed by React and triggers the component to rerender.

> Another thing is, if we can update using `count + 1`, why can't we do so
> using `count++`?

In React we ***absolutely DO NOT*** mutate state. The `count++`, if it *could* work and not throw an error, would still be a state mutation. Trying to use `count++` is the same as trying to do `count = count + 1` which we just simply don't do in React.

In more general Javascript terms, trying to post-increment with `count++` while `count` is declared `const` would throw an error. When a variable is declared `const` this only means it can't have a value reassigned to it *after* initialization. This ***doesn't*** mean that the value currently assigned is static/constant. If we had declared `let [count, setCount] = useState(0)` then by Javascript standards doing `count++` is perfectly legal.

We use the React state updater functions to enqueue state updates and generally return *new* object/value references.

Comment: May I clarify what state mutation means? Does it mean that the ```count``` variable is changed outside of the setCount function, i.e. it is being changed in the statement ```count = count + 1``` (which is the wrong way)? I'm interpreting that based on the first answer from: https://github.com/sudheerj/reactjs-interview-questions/issues/101. Following, is the correct way to use setCount to update the ```count``` object in the array to ```count + 1``` when we explicitly state ```setCount(count + 1)```?

Comment: @chu-js Yes, effectively *exactly* that. But consider also when the state is an object, say `const [state, setState] = useState({ count: 0 })` and you simply do `state.count++`. The `state` is declared const, but you can mutate properties. This is also anti-pattern in react. Using the state updater function alone *still* isn't enough as you can still mutate the state, i.e. `setState(state => { state.count++; return state; })`, the `state` object is still the same object reference from the previous render cycle. React state should be considered immutable.

Comment: First, thanks so much for clarifying! Appreciate your help. I understand that the properties of ```state``` can be mutated. However, you lost me at the anti-pattern part. What does anti-pattern mean?

Comment: @chu-js The term "anti-pattern" is basically a way of saying that not only is the "thing" you are trying to do not a correct way of doing it, but it's *really* not the correct way, it is the wrong way. If design patterns are the established ways to solve common problems, then anti-patterns are the antithesis of this. They are prone to cause more issues than they solve. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern Mutating state in React is anti-pattern because it makes it harder/impossible for React to run its reconciliation algorithm to compute rendering diffs.

Answer (score 0):

The hook remains immutable in the scope of the function. When you change it, the component re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

Type `const` in JS doesn't prevent you from making operations on the variable. Adding or subtraction of values will be interpreted without any issues. This the count is increasing.

However `count`++ shorthand is written for `count = count + 1` where a assignment operation is taking place and it is prohibited by the type const.

Comment: When you define a variable by const assignment is not allowed. if you define const and do variable++ it will throw an error